# getting a 500 internal server error when using ajax with symfony

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

i am trying to use ajax with symfony 2 but i get the error 500, for my url i am using jsrouterbundle her's my route:

```
      vote:
           pattern:     /vote
           defaults:  { _controller: UserBundle:User:vote}
           options:
           expose: true
```

and this is my js function:

```
          function vote(res) {
             var path=Routing.generate('vote');
             alert(path);
             $.ajax({
                     method: "POST",
                     url: path,
                     data: {vote: "Positif", id:res}
             })
             .done(function (msg) {
                    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
              });
          }
```

and this where i call that function

```
        <img alt="test" onclick='vote("{{ result.id }}")'/>
```

her's my php controller

```
           public function voteAction(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $vote= $request->get("vote");
        $id= $request->get("id");
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $rep = $em->getRepository('LoginBundle:Resultat');
        $resultat = $rep->findOneBy($id);
        if ($resultat) {
            $resultat->setVote($vote);
            $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->render('LoginBundle:Login:inscription.html.twig');
    }

    return $this->render('LoginBundle:Login:inscription.html.twig');
}
```

i guess the problem is the route but i don't know to resolve this

thanks for your help

Comment: `options:` is it correct, or `{}`/`''` should be given

Comment: @Tushar Looks like it should just be removed maybe?

Comment: `500` means error on server. There is error in your `php` file

Comment: @Tushar options is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the your JavaScript function path line

```
var path=Routing.generate('vote');
```

To following

```
var path="Routing.generate('vote')";
```

Comment: it do not give me anymore the 500 error but the controller is not working, and to test i add in the first lines of that controller code to insert in the database but it's not doing that

Comment: Please check your route file

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that it's solved, your solution worked fine, it's just i had some issues in the code of the controller . thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

On developing mod for your site(Run code on **dev** mode, Run code on app_dev.php). And there you will get real error behind the **500 error** .

Comment: What does this mean? How do I run the code in app_dev.php